# Probability based on aggregated data with overlapping data points

Tags: probability, likelihood

Say I have 20 individuals:

- 2 of them did event $A$
- 8 others did event $B$
- 10 did both events $A$ and $B$

Therefore, I can build the following table:

```
  Did 1 action  Did 2 actions  
A            2             10  
B            8             10
```

Here is how I want to interpret this:

- Given that someone did event $A$, they have a `10/12` (80%) chance to have also done $B$
- Given that someone did event $B$, they have a `10/18` (55%) chance to have also done $A$
- On average, given that someone has done an event, $A$ or $B$, that person has a 67.5% chance to have done another

Now if I describe my data like this:

```
 Did 1 action  Did 2 actions  
           10             10
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this compared to the data above. In the first table, I think I have the probability of $A+B$ given $A$ and the probability of $A+B$ given $B$. In the other table, I have the probability of $A+B$ given ($A$ or $B$).

But if this is a real world example, and I want to know what is the likelihood that someone will commit the second action given that they have already committed one, what probability should I retain?

Can these figures be interpreted as probabilities at all or am I making a mistake there as well? Am I using the wrong metrics / methodology?

Comment: Is $A+B$ the event $A \cup B$ [$A$ OR $B$ (or both)] or $A \cap B$ [$A$ AND $B$]?

Comment: What I wrote as A+B meant A∩B, sorry for the confusion. I will correct this soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone in the group of 20 did A or B.
Given that they are in the group (did A or B), the chances that they did both is 50% (10 of the 20).

Comment: I understand this. But can I say that if I randomly pick someone who did A or someone who did B, then that person has a 70% chance (on average) to have done both A and B?

Comment: I'm trying to interpret this as applied to a case where A and B have similar meanings, and I want to understand which figure is appropriate. For instance, if it were a game, I could say A means finishing the world called A and B means finishing the world called B. The idea is: what is my probability of having finished both worlds given that I've finished a world?

Comment: Hi Konrad, I actually don't see where you are getting 70%.

Comment: I've edited my question, it's 67.5% (.55+.80)/2. I could do a weighted average too, but the basic idea was to take the average of the probabilities of each group.

Comment: OK, I see what you did now - thanks!  I believe the problem is that the averaging model implies a world where A or B is chosen first, and then a 2nd is chosen later.  In this situation, A then B is different than B then A, whereas in this problem you just have AB, A ~B, and ~A B.  So this might be OK for the finishing a world situation.